# Using androidTestImplementation class in Activity

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

Its just an experiment but can I use `AppiumDriver` class that belong to dependency declared as

```
androidTestImplementation 'io.appium:java-client:6.1.0'
```

in the activity and not in `InstrumentedTest` class of `Android`?